# How to use Print Styles in an Angular 7 App

Tags: css, angular

I need to print a html form (within an Angular7 App) with minimal margins. The only way thus far I can achieve this is to use Chrome and to adjust the margins manually via the print preview box.

I have tried adding @media print styles & @page styles in both the component css file and the main global stylesheet. I even tried changing the background colour of the html and body tags to green just to see if something was happening. I have changed the rendering in Chrome to print styles so I can see the affects of the CSS, yet still no affect is visible

Tried in both component.css and styles.css

```
@page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background: green;
}

@media print{
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        background: green;
    }
}
```

The background green is just so I can see if it works. I will remove when I get it working.

I expect to see the background to go green on the html and body tags when I render to the screen the print styles (or in the print-preview window)

I get no green colour change to the html or body tags and the margins stay at the default amounts.

Comment: I also tried using cm and mm on the margin amount but the margins remained at the default. That is why I tried the green colour change to see if I could see changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "!important" for each rule?

```
@page {
   size: auto !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

@media print{
 html, body {
   margin: 0 !important;
      background: green !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it is because the body tag is not created by the component that it is not working. When I place the rule on an element created in the component html it works. This still does not help me when setting the overall page margins.